# "Pin down" an automatically installed package so apt-get autoremove keeps it

Tags: apt, package-management

Say I install package A, which depends on package B. Then I remove A.

Now `apt-get autoremove` wants to remove B, but I want to keep it. How do I "pin down" B so that the system acts as if I installed B myself?

I come from Gentoo, where the solution would be to add B to my `world` file. What's the Debian/Ubuntu equivalent?

Answer (score 10):

- You can use

  ```
  sudo apt-mark manual some_package
  ```

  to mark `some_package` as manually installed so that it *doesn't get* autoremoved.
- You can use

  ```
  sudo apt-mark auto some_package
  ```

  to mark `some-package` as automatically installed so that it *gets* autoremoved.

Comment: Wouldn't  an explicitly `install` on B do the same? Or is a `--reinstall` needed?

Comment: @Rmano, `sudo apt-get install some-package` would work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hold a package, so it won't get auto-removed while running `sudo apt-get autoremove` command.

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

To unhold the holded package,

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```

**Example:**

```
$ sudo apt-get -s autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Remv apache2-bin [2.4.7-1ubuntu4]
Remv apache2-data [2.4.7-1ubuntu4]
Remv libaprutil1-ldap [1.5.3-1]
Remv libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 [1.5.3-1]
Remv libaprutil1 [1.5.3-1]
Remv libapr1 [1.5.0-1]

$ sudo apt-mark hold apache2-bin
apache2-bin set on hold.

$ sudo apt-get -s autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-data
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Remv apache2-data [2.4.7-1ubuntu4]
```