# How to exclude a package from apt-get autoremove?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm in a situation where the list of orphaned packages to be removed by `apt-get autoremove` includes a package that I want to keep. Apparently I have accidentally removed a package which was depending on it. How can I now mark the package as explicitly desired, so that `apt-get autoremove` will not remove it?

Comment: And the related question: [Why is it orphaned at all?](https://askubuntu.com/q/943287/161463)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Pin down" an automatically installed package so apt-get autoremove keeps it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456602/pin-down-an-automatically-installed-package-so-apt-get-autoremove-keeps-it)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `apt-mark`

```
$ man apt-mark
...
manual
       manual is used to mark a package as being manually installed, which will 
prevent the package from being automatically removed if no other packages 
depend on it.
```

So

```
sudo apt-mark manual <package-name>
```

Now `autoremove` won't remove it.

To undo

```
sudo apt-mark auto <package-name>
```

Now `autoremove` will remove the package if it is not a dependency of any other package.

Comment: Another handy trick is that you can mark many packages at once like this:   sudo apt-mark manual <package1> <package2> <package3> etc

Answer (score 10):

A few more Google attempts brought up a [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/209293/how-to-remove-package-from-apt-get-autoremove-queue):

It is either possible to just install explicitly:

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

or marking as manually installed via

```
sudo apt-mark manual <package>
```

`apt` won't re-install, the output will just look like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tmux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tmux is already the newest version.
tmux set to manually installed.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered well, but I found a situation where I did not want to "mark" many of the packages (and then un-mark them after `autoremove`).

When the list of packages you *want* to autoremove is easily-defined, then you can pipe/`sed`/`xargs` them out.

I don't have a complex example of many packages, but if I have the following scenario:

```bsh
root@fptc-rsvrd:~# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common linux-headers-4.4.0-141 linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-143 linux-headers-4.4.0-143-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-146 linux-headers-4.4.0-146-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic linux-image-4.4.0-146-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-146-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-146-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-141-generic pandoc-data
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 18 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
After this operation, 907 MB disk space will be freed.
```

and I want to remove just the `linux*` packages, I can do this:

```bsh
root@fptc-rsvrd:~# apt-get autoremove -s | sed -ne 's/Remv \(linux[^[]*\)\[.*/\1/gp'
linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-141
linux-headers-4.4.0-143-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-143
linux-headers-4.4.0-146-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-146
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-143-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic
linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-146-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-146-generic
linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic
linux-modules-4.4.0-146-generic
```

So from here, it's easy to pass these via `xargs` as command-line arguments to the simple `apt-get remove -y`:

```bsh
apt-get autoremove -s \
  | sed -ne 's/Remv \(linux[^[]*\)\[.*/\1/gp' \
  | xargs apt-get remove -y
```

Normally when using `xargs`, I'd guard against spaces in the arguments (e.g., `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`), but since package names don't have spaces in them, I'm comfortable using newline-delimited arguments.

(I'd think it other situations, it'd be more appropriate to "mark" a hold, the unhold the packages. That can also be done with regexes and `xargs`, but is probably over-engineering the situation.)